# Create a Pandas Column that Starts with x and Incremented by y

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, increment

I want to create another column in my pandas DataFrame (New_Column) that has a starting value of x and then the subsequent rows are incremented by y (or takes the previous row and adds y).

For example: starting value of 2000, increment by 7

```
Index  Date        New_Column
0      10-02-2020  2000
1      10-01-2020  2007
2      09-30-2020  2014
3      09-29-2020  2021
```

I add the date column because that is the only column in my DataFrame that is unique, don't know if this matters. I am working in Google's Colaboratory. I have tried using a for loop to no avail, as well as other Stack users index suggestions.

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried to write?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new column data before adding it to your dataframe. You can see an example in the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [ "10-02-2020","10-01-2020","09-30-2020","09-29-2020"]})
newData = []
starting = 2000
incr = 7
numRows = len(df.index)
for i in range(0,numRows):
    newData.append(starting)
    starting+=incr
df["New_Column"] = newData
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy's [`arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2020-09-29', periods=4, freq='D')[::-1]})
start_val = 2000
increm = 7
df['New column'] = np.arange(start=start_val, stop=start_val+len(df)*increm, step=increm)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```py
        Date  New column
0 2020-10-02        2000
1 2020-10-01        2007
2 2020-09-30        2014
3 2020-09-29        2021
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df['new'] = np.arange(x, x+len(df)*y, y)
```